# Question about probability with coins

Tags: probability

If we have one coin, the probability to get tails is $50$%.

If we have $10$ coins and drop them at the same time, is logical to think that the lost common combination is $5$ tails and $5$ cross but, because each coin is individual, wouldn't be so probable to get $1$ tails and $9$ cross than $5$ of each?

Comment: You have typos and poor grammar.  I assume that you are asking if getting $5$ tails and $5$ heads in some order will be the most common result.  It will, and occurs with probability $\dfrac{\binom{10}{5}}{2^{10}}\approx 0.2461$ which is greater than the probability of getting $1$ tail and $9$ heads which is instead $\dfrac{\binom{10}{1}}{2^{10}}\approx 0.0098$.  [Read more about the binomial distribution here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is helpful to list all the outcomes. With $10$ coins there are $2^{10} = 1024$ possible outcomes, which is too many to do here. But $4$ coins only has $16$ possible outcomes which is reasonable, and should show you what is going on. Number the coins from $1$ to $4$, then the possible outcomes are:

$$\begin{array}{cccc|c}\#1&\#2&\#3&\#4&\text{Number of Heads}\\\hline 
H&H&H&H&4\\H&H&H&T&3\\H&H&T&H&3\\H&H&T&T&2\\
H&T&H&H&3\\H&T&H&T&2\\H&T&T&H&2\\H&T&T&T&1\\ 
T&H&H&H&3\\T&H&H&T&2\\T&H&T&H&2\\T&H&T&T&1\\
T&T&H&H&2\\T&T&H&T&1\\T&T&T&H&1\\T&T&T&T&0\end{array}$$

Because each individual coin has a probability of $\frac 12$ of landing on heads, and probability of $\frac 12$ of landing on tails, independent of the other coins, the probability of any of these outcomes is going to be $$\left(\frac 12\right)\left(\frac 12\right)\left(\frac 12\right)\left(\frac 12\right) = \frac 1{16}$$

But what you asked for is the probability that half of them (two in this case) are heads. Note that there is

- $1$ outcome with $0$ heads and $4$ tails
- $4$ outcomes with $1$ head and $3$ tails
- $6$ outcomes with $2$ heads and $2$ tails
- $4$ outcomes with $3$ heads and $1$ tail
- $1$ outcome with $4$ heads and $0$ tails.

So the probability of $2$ heads and $2$ tails is $$6 \times \frac 1{16} = \frac 38$$ simply because there are more ways to have $2$ heads and $2$ tails than the other possible combinations.